# How to update foreign key from another model Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm fairly new to Django, I have two models usecase and usecase_type.
usecase table has a fk of usecase_type. I'm trying to update usecase details including the usecase_type value.

How can I update the value plus show the usecase_type in a dropdown list to update.

My views.py:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
    try:
        usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
        context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0]}
        if request.method == "POST":
            usecase_name = request.POST['usecase_name']
            usecase_description = request.POST['usecase_description']
            usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']
            usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
            usecase_details.usecase_name = usecase_name
            usecase_details.usecase_description = usecase_description
            usecase_details.usecase_type_id = usecase_type 

            usecase_details.save()
            if usecase_details:
                messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
        return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', context)
    except:
        messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
```

my template:

```
{% block body %}

<div class="row  d-flex">
    <div class="col-12 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-light shadow-sm components-section  d-flex ">
            <div class="card-body  d-flex ">
                <div class="row mb-4">                 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row col-12">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <h3 class="h3">Edit usecase details:</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <li role="separator" class="dropdown-divider border-black mb-3 ml-3"></li> -->
                        <form action="/update-usecase/{{usecase_details.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Usecase name:</label>
                                    <input value="{{usecase_details.usecase_name}}" type="text" name="usecase_name" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="" required>                           
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Usecase description:</label>
                                    <input value="{{usecase_details.usecase_description}}" type="text" name="usecase_description" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="" required>                             
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                              <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase Type:</label>
                                <select name="usecase_type" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="usecase_type">
                                    <option value="0" selected>{{usecase_details.usecase_type_id}}</option>
                                    {% for usecase_type in uctype %}
                                    <option value="{{usecase_type.usecase_type_id}}">{{usecase_type.usecase_type_name}}</option>
                                    {% endfor %}                                
                                  </select>                          
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Changes">
                          </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

models:

```
class Usecase(models.Model):
    usecase_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    usecase_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
    usecase_type = models.ForeignKey('UsecaseType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usecase'

class UsecaseType(models.Model):
    usecase_type_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
    usecase_type_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'usecase_type'
```

I'm missing something cause I'm not getting the values in the dropdown list and I'm getting error while updating usecase description and name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field of `ForeignKey` is referring to only 1 object, you cannot loop over it. If you want all `UsecaseType` objects as options, then pass it to the context:

```
context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0], "usecase_types": UsecaseType.objects.all()}
```

Then change the loop into:

```
{% for usecase_type in usecase_types %}
<option value="{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_id }}">{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: works as expected, except I want to show the names of usecase_type not the id in the options. plus I'm not able to change the usecase description and name alone, it only accept changes when I change the usecase_type as well any idea why?

Comment: You probably need to learn about relationships in Django. Please read this carefully: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: thanks! I'll I've using Django for 3 weeks I need this

Answer (score 1):

`usecase_type` field in the  `Usecase` model is an object (instance) of the `UsecaseType` model. What I assume you want to do is to obtain the `UsecaseType` object, then update the relevant instance of `Usecase`.
Assuming `usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']` is an id, you can do:

```
usecase_type_obj= UsecaseType.objects.get(usecase_type_id=usecase_type)
usecase_details.usecase_type=usecase_type_obj
usecase_details.save()
```

(If usecase_type refers to the name, simply  change the above code to `.get(usecase_type_name =usecase_type).`

Note:
Why your approach does not work is that you are trying to assign a string to `usecase_details.usecase_type_id`, but `usecase_type_id` is not an attribute of `usecase_details`, but an attribute of  `usecase_type` related object. I also suggest changing the variable name `usecase_type` to `usecase_type_id` or `usecase_type_name` depending what you accept from post.

Comment: I'm getting an error 302 response

Comment: @JHS99 302 is a redirect, not an error response. Propably related to login/authentication.